# Script files returning 404 Error

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I'm using ASP.Net and whenever I create a script file or try to include a script file like jQuery they aren't working. I am doing just a regular localhost server and none of the scripts are working. Upon further examination using firebug I look at whats being referenced in those scripts and it shows html code for a 404 error. I know the scripts and files are there and I can navigate directly to them in the browser but for some reason I can't reference them in my page.

Here is a screenshot:

[404 Error http://img517.imageshack.us/img517/8058/404z.png](http://img517.imageshack.us/img517/8058/404z.png)

[alt text http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/174/4042.png](http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/174/4042.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is rather straightforward to me.

The webpage: `http://localhost:49464/Seth-Duncan.com/Main.aspx`
The jquery: `http://localhost:49464/scripts/jquery-1.4.2-min.js`

Unsurprisingly, there doesn't seem to be a jquery script there. Most likely, it *would* work fine on the production server.

Comment: I don't think it's quite that simple, I say this because I reference the stylesheet in the exact same manner and it references fine, it's just the scripts in the script folder

Comment: Correction, it was that simple, I changed it to not use the Seth-Duncan.com/ folder name and just use root and it all works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

My bet is that the relative reference to the script:

```
../script/jquery-1.4.2-min.js
```

breaks because your current page is in a directory where it won't work. (maybe caused by a rewritten URL).

Can you show

- What URL you are on
- What absolute directory the scripts reside in?

Comment: URL: http://localhost:49464/Seth-Duncan.com/Main.aspx

Directory structure: See Above Second Image

Answer (score 0):

The path to the scripts file is wrong - there is ".." in it. You should specify path on the server, not on the file system.

Comment: There's nothing wrong about specifying a relative path in a web server with ".."

The only problem is that the files must be at that location as Pekka said.

Comment: I see, thanks. For some reason I though that Seth Duncan used file system path.